# Ajax form not working on page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I am trying to post dynamically generated form data using ajax/jquery.(method =post).

I am able to retrieve the submitted data (displayed in console) using request.getParameterNames in my servlet,but only once.
My servlet displays a text in the browser after it displays the request parameter in the console.

If I click the back button and go back to the form and resubmit, or refresh the form and resubmit, the form still invokes the servlet, but request.getParameterNames does not retrieve any of my form data.

ajax code

```
    $('#submit').click(function(e){  
 e.preventDefault();
  alert('got here');
  $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Surveyoutput',
    data: $("#form1").serialize(),  
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
        if ( data ) { alert ('Got Data'); } else { alert('No Data'); }
      }
    });    
    return false;  
  });
```

FORM

```
  <form  name ="form1" id="form1" action = "Surveyoutput" method = "post">
  <input type="submit" id = "submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

SERVLET

```
       @WebServlet("/Surveyoutput")
       public class Surveyoutput extends HttpServlet {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       out.println("test successful");

        Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();  
       while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) 
     {  
      String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();  
      String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);  
       System.out.println(paramName);
     System.out.println(paramValue); 
     }
```

I am new to ajax and not able to figure the mistake. Any help would be great!

Comment: Why not try the POST using FormData?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData  Makes it super easy to send data using a POST request.

Comment: check the network tab of your browsers developer toolbar to see the ajax request and the requested parameters

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks a lot..I can see the request parameters both the times I submitted.. textbox_1=ssss&time_1=0&textbox_2=rrrr&time_2=0&submit=Submit           textbox_1=mmm&time_1=0&textbox_2=xxx&time_2=0&submit=Submit ......but i am not sure why its not getting displayed in eclipse console when i do a request.getParameters from servlet...

Comment: put a break point in the controller method and see whether the control is reaching there

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks. It works. For some reason, the values were not initially getting displayed in the eclipse  console when i used System.out.println from the servlet. Thanks for pointing out how to debug using the developer toolbar..its helps a lot!